# Xpath to go back to sibing td

Tags: xpath

I am trying to back to to previous td but to no avail, can you help

//*[@class='ein' and contains(.,'aaaa')] gets me to td but need to select the previous td-tried below but did not work

//*[@class='ein' and contains(.,'aaaa')][preceding-sibling::td]

Comment: Give the HTML please..to help you out.We need to see the Dom structure

Answer (score 1):

Remember `/X` means "select X", while `[X]` means "where X". If you want to select preceding siblings, rather than testing whether they exist, use `/`.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say for certain without seeing the input HTML but I suspect that instead of

```
//*[@class='ein' and contains(.,'aaaa')][preceding-sibling::td]
```

you need something like

```
//*[@class='ein' and contains(.,'aaaa')]/preceding-sibling::td[1]
```

to navigate from each node selected by the initial expression to its nearest preceding `td`.  Your first attempt will select exactly the same nodes as

```
//*[@class='ein' and contains(.,'aaaa')]
```

but only if they have at least one preceding-sibling element named `td`.

Answer (score 0):

> Use // after the element you found
> Instead of preceding-sibling, just use preceding

//*[@class='ein' and contains(.,'aaaa')]//preceding::td[1]